# jquery fadein on buttonclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a Bootstrap site and I want jQuery to fade in my text on a button click. This is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.hidden').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('hidden');
});

$(#homebutton).onclick(function() {
  $('#homebutton.hidden').fadein(1000).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">J&J Services</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section1">Information</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section class=" section0 homecontent col-md-12">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="hidden" style="display:none;">
        <h1>welcome to J&J services.
          <hr>
          <button id="homebutton" class="btn btn-success btn-large">
            <a href="#section1">click here to learn about us today.</a>
        </h1>
      </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="section1 information ">
      <div class="container-fluid hidden"></div>
    </section>
    </div>
</section>
```

I'm new to jQuery and I don't know what I did wrong. Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your HTML has some issues, notably some missing/misplaced closing `</div>` and `</button>` tags

Comment: Check the browser console for errors. Also it makes no sense to put an `<a>` inside a `<button>`; you just need one or the other.

Comment: `$(#homebutton)` should be `$("#homebutton")`

Comment: invalid or unexpected  token on this line: $(#homebutton).onclick(function () {

Comment: Can you tell where are you including your jQuery and Script file in HTML?
Probably - $(#homebutton) is not getting the reference as you have included the Script before the DIV.

Either you can move the Script to bottom, or refactor your code to add the event listener inside $(document).ready();

Comment: i included my script at  the bottom of the body element

Comment: @JasperScheper, your code has multiple issues. Please revise the `HTML`. An improvement is of `jQuery` code can be found on my answer. But some things don't add up, because of missing code.

Comment: thanks all. it's working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With revised HTML and jquery targets:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.section0 .hidden').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('hidden');
});
$('#homebutton').on('click', function() {
   $('.section1 .hidden').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">J&amp;J Services</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#section1">Information</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <section class="section0 homecontent col-md-12">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="hidden" style="display:none;">
        <h1>welcome to J&amp;J services.
          <hr>
          <button id="homebutton" class="btn btn-success btn-large">
            click here to learn about us today.
          </button>
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="section1 information ">
    <div class="container-fluid hidden" style="display:none;">Information</div>
  </section>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanna fade in `section1` text when u click the button, update like this:

```
$('#homebutton').on('click', function() {
   $('.container-fluid').fadeIn(1000).removeClass('hidden');
});
```